# bitwise operator from different type with opencv

Tags: opencv, bitwise-operators, intrinsics

I frequently encounter that issue but I don't really know a proper way to fix it.
I just would like some advise to do it the regarding to the processing time.

I am using opencv and I want to realize that operation:

```
map |= mask & mu(0);
```

`map` is a matrix of single precision float.

`mask` is a matrix of unsigned char that only contain 0 for the statement *false* ot 255 (0xFF) for the statement *true*

`mu` is a double precision float scalar value.

Usually I do realize that operation that way :

```
cv::multiply(mask,mu(0),mask, 1./255., CV_32F);
map |= mask
```

Regarding also to the transparent vectorize classes (header openc2/core/hal/intrinsics.hpp) is there a more efficient way to do such operation ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: how about bitwise opencv operations like [bitwise_and](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) it accepts mat and scalar.

Comment: You are right the bitwise_or (bitwise_and and bitwise_xor as well) can have a mask as parameter. So my equation can be fix using bitwise_or(map,mu,map,mask).
Thank you for your help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  highlighted by [api55](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888688/api55) could be fix by using directly the bitwise function rather than using the operator overload.

Thank you [api55](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888688/api55)